# visibility gone of image view when come from 2nd activity to 1st activity using putextra and getextra method in android

Tags: java, android

everyone. I am new in android. I am creating two activities in android ,1st activity has two image view and one button . and 2nd activity has one button. when  I go to second activity and then from second activity agian . one image view of 1st activity should visibility gone. how can i do this.

here is my code

```
Activitymain.xml


  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/1stimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/2ndimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="go to second activity" />


   mainactivity.java



     ImageView imageView1, imageView2;
            Button btn;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.1stimage);
                imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.2ndimage);
                btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent Firstintent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                        startActivity(Firstintent);

                    }
                });

            }
secondactivity.xml

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="go to 1st activity" />

secondactivity.java

    Button btn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent SecondIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    SecondActivity.this.startActivity(SecondIntent);
                    SecondActivity.this.finishActivity();

                }
            });
        }
```

please help me

Comment: Just before starting the second activity, set the visibility of your ImageView to GONE.

Comment: You want to change the visibility to GONE when the second activity ends right? To figure out how to use Intents and their extras?

Answer (score 0):

Use `putextra(tag, some variable to use in mainActivity)` and `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); extras.get[type of variable](tag)` to pass a variable (probably a boolean) to tell the onCreate() to show or not show the pic.

**EDIT:**
Here is one way to implement it: in the first activity:

1) Check if there are extras (A.K.A. if second activity was loaded/ there is a true)

2) If (yes) { if (first pic is loaded) { remove first pic } else if (first pick is not but second is loaded) { remove second pic } ... for all the pictures you want to do this to.

Remember you only need to pass true/false from the second activity (and then handle it in the first/one being modified)

Comment: Thnx. but everytime when I go from first activity to second activity and then go from second activity to first activity imagview visibilty should gone one by one.for example for 1st time 1st image invisible and second time secon imagone gone. please do this for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Activitymain.xml


  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/1stimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/2ndimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="go to second activity" />


   mainactivity.java



     ImageView imageView1, imageView2;
            Button btn;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.1stimage);
                imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.2ndimage);
                btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent Firstintent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                        startActivity(Firstintent);

                    }
                });
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if(extras != null){
                   if(extras.getBoolean("isResult", false)){
                      imageView1.setVisability(View.GONE);
                   }
                }

            }
secondactivity.xml

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="go to 1st activity" />

secondactivity.java

    Button btn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent SecondIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    SecondIntent.putExtra("isResult", true);
                    SecondActivity.this.startActivity(SecondIntent);
                    SecondActivity.this.finishActivity();

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thnx. but everytime when I go from first activity to second activity and then go from second activity to first activity imagview visibilty should gone one by one.for example for 1st time 1st image invisible and second time secon imagone gone. please do this for me

Comment: images must be hiding in turn, I understood correctly?